# What are some further examples of proper class models of ZF that are contained in their own "self-relativization"?

Tags: set-theory, model-theory

Let $\Gamma$ and $\Delta$ be theories in the language of set theory (LST), and let $M = \{x: \phi(x)\}$ be a class, where $\phi(x)$ is some formula of LST.  Let us say that $M$ is a (standard) class model of $\Gamma$ in $\Delta$ if and only if $\Gamma \vdash \psi$ implies $\Delta \vdash \psi^M$ for all sentences $\psi$ of LST, where $\psi^M$ denotes the relativization of $\psi$ to the class $M$.  I'm curious about what can be said of proper class models $M$ of ZF in ZF such that $\mbox{ZF} \vdash \forall x (x \in M \rightarrow \phi^M(x)$), i.e., $\mbox{ZF} \vdash \forall x (\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi^M(x))$.

A class $M = \{x: \phi(x)\}$ satisfying $\forall x (\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi^M(x))$ could be said to be "contained in its self-relativization."  Using Definition I.16.5 from Kunen's set theory book (2013), the statement $\forall x (\phi(x) \rightarrow \phi^M(x))$ (i.e., $(\forall x \, \phi(x))^\phi)$) holds if and only if $\phi$ is absolute for $\{x:\phi(x)\}$, written $\{x: \phi(x)\} \preceq_\phi V$.

Examples of such proper class models of ZF satisfying this self-relativization property are $V$ and $L$ (and both satisfy the stronger condition $\mbox{ZF} \vdash \forall x (\phi(x) \leftrightarrow \phi^M(x)$).  Note also that the canonical inner models $L[0^\sharp]$, $L[\mu]$, etc., are transitive class models of ZF that satisfy the self-relativization property, but their consistency strength is well beyond that of ZF.

My questions are as follows.  What are some other interesting examples and non-examples?  Am I correct in thinking that HOD is a non-example? Are there examples besides $V$ and $L$ whose existence is equiconsistent with ZF?  And is there an example that is non-transitive?

One interesting thing about such class models $M$ of ZF in ZF is that ZF does not refute $V = M$ if ZF is consistent, for if $\mbox{ZF} \vdash \neg \forall x (\phi(x))$, then $\mbox{ZF} \vdash \neg \forall x (x\in M \rightarrow \phi^M(x))$, and therefore $\mbox{ZF} \nvdash \forall x (x \in M \rightarrow \phi^M(x))$, assuming ZF is consistent.  This is what piqued my interest in the question. Also, one of the comments points out that, if ZF proves that $M$ is non-transitive, then ZF refutes $V = M$.  Thus, if there is a non-transitive example, then ZF cannot prove that it is non-transitive.  But could there be one that isn't transitive according to a theory stronger than ZF?  (Maybe no such theory would be very natural or attractive.)

Comment: Does not every model of ZF contains its own L, which is just the ordinary L if the model is transitive and contains all ordinals?

Comment: Yes, so $M$ is transitive if and only if it contains $L$, if and only if it contains all the ordinals.  I guess I can simplify my question now.

Comment: If $ZF$ proves that $M$ is non-transitive, then $ZF$ refutes $V=M$.

Comment: Ah, so I'd have to have one of stronger consistency strength than ZF.  Maybe it's possible to have a stronger theory $\Gamma$ prove such an $M$ non-transitive, but not ZF, so $\Gamma$ refutes $V = M$, but ZF doesn't?

Comment: I edited it to take that into account.  Maybe it's still a bad question.

Comment: Here's an honest question. What's the fascination with non-transitive models? Once you collapse them, you end up with a transitive model. So it's not like you're missing out some kind of information by not allowing transitive models.

Comment: One reason I suppose is that one might not want necessarily to assume the axiom of foundation, and without that you can't collapse the model. In the last of my questions, I was wondering if $L$ is the minimal model satisfying the self-relativization property without having to assume transitivity.

Comment: After the last comment: You want a self-relativizing class model not containing $L$ in $ZF$. If $ZF$ proves that $M$ does not contain $L$, then it refutes $V=M$, as in my previous comment. So there are no $ZF$-provable examples. If we drop the self-relativization condition, then we can build something like "the universe of sets transitively containing $\emptyset$ as an element". This is a class model (its collapse is just $V$) not containing $L$, but it is not self-relativizing.

Comment: I took that as the content of your previous comment (and I was aware the non-self-relativizing example).  I still feel like I can't say, "$L$ is the minimal self-relativizing proper class model of ZF," since ZF doesn't seem to prove that;, rather, it can't disprove it.  I haven't ruled out the case where an $M$ is provably non-transitive in some extension of ZF, but not in ZF.  It would seem to be like concluding "there are no inaccessible cardinals" just because ZF can't prove that there are any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $AC$ stand for the axiom of choice, let $L$ denote the constructible universe and let $L^*$ the universe of constructible sets transitively containing $\emptyset$ as an element.
Although $L^*$ is a proper subclass of $L$, it collapses to $L$, so it is isomorphic to $L$.

Let $\phi(x)$ be the formula

- $(AC\rightarrow x\in L)\wedge(\neg AC\rightarrow x\in L^*)$.

I claim that the corresponding class $M$ is a model of $ZFC$ in $ZF$. In fact, $M$ is either $L$ or  $L^*$, so it is a model of $ZFC$ in any case.
(This argument can be made precise: $ZF\vdash AC\rightarrow (\psi^M\leftrightarrow \psi^L)$ and $ZF\vdash \neg AC\rightarrow (\psi^M\leftrightarrow \psi^{L^*})$, for any $\psi$. Therefore $\psi^M$ holds for all $ZFC$ axioms).

Now, I claim that $M$ is self-relativizing. Indeed, $ZF\vdash AC^M$, so $ZF\vdash \phi(x)^M\leftrightarrow (x\in L)^M$. But $L^M$ is $M$ in both cases, because $M$ is either $L$ or $L^*$, and $L^*$ is isomorphic to $L$. Therefore, $ZF\vdash \phi(x)^M\leftrightarrow \phi(x)$.

Finally, $ZF$ cannot prove that $L\subseteq M$, and $ZF+\neg AC$ proves that $M$ is a proper sublass of $L$.

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you!